# Adwords API PHP - Can you Pause AdGroup

Tags: php, api, google-ads-api

I have successfully managed to use the PauseAd.php example in the AdWords PHP SDK but it only will Pause/Enable at ad level. Where my project needs to be able pause/enable adgroup level and wanted to know if it is possible.

Im currently using version v201607

Thanks

Comment: The Google Adwords API v201607 does not exists anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Pausing at Adgroup level is possible, You just need to modify the script **UpdateAdGroup.php** at

> googleads-php-lib/examples/AdWords/v201607/BasicOperations/UpdateAdGroup.php
>   slightly

and set the `Adgroup.Status` to `PAUSE`

See at **Github**: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/v201607/BasicOperations/UpdateAdGroup.php

See at **Adword**: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201607/AdGroupService.AdGroup#status

Comment: `PAUSE` or `PAUSED` ? In one piece of documentation am seeing it with a 'D'  https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/python/basic-operations